# Setting S3 output file grantees for spark output files

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I'm running Spark on AWS EMR and I'm having some issues getting the correct permissions on the output files (`rdd.saveAsTextFile('<file_dir_name>')`).  In hive, I would add a line in the beginning with `set fs.s3.canned.acl=BucketOwnerFullControl` and that would set the correct permissions.  For Spark, I tried running:

```
hadoop jar /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-3HIRLHJJXV3SJ/script-runner.jar \
/home/hadoop/spark/bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn-cluster \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dfs.s3.canned.acl=BucketOwnerFullControl" \ 
hdfs:///user/hadoop/spark.py
```

But the permissions do not get set properly on the output files.  What is the proper way to pass in the 'fs.s3.canned.acl=BucketOwnerFullControl' or any of the S3 canned permissions to the spark job?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution.  In the job, you have to access the JavaSparkContext and from there get the Hadoop configuration and set the parameter there.  For example:

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3.canned.acl','BucketOwnerFullControl')
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to pass hadoop config keys in spark is to use `--conf` with keys prefixed with `spark.hadoop.`. Your command would look like

```
hadoop jar /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-3HIRLHJJXV3SJ/script-runner.jar \
/home/hadoop/spark/bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn-cluster \
--conf "spark.hadoop.fs.s3.canned.acl=BucketOwnerFullControl" \ 
hdfs:///user/hadoop/spark.py
```

Unfortunately I cannot find any reference in official documentation of spark.